# Sharepoint Online Analytics access without giving site owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, modern-experience, web-analytics

Is there a way to give someone access to see the analytics without giving them full admin rights into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Microsoft official documentation at: [View usage data for your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e),

> Only site admins, site owners, and **site members** can view site usage data

So, you can assign the **Members** permissions to your user and then can access the site analytics.

Comment: that worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e), you could add users into site members group with edit permission.
[image]